# hardcode item to list in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, case

I have the following query which lists items in a specific order that I wanted. Now I want to hard code a value to be displayed along with the other values but this value doesn't exist in my table and I don't want to add it.

Here's the query:

```
select item_name from item_table
order by 
    case 
        when item_name = 'New' then 1 
        when item_name = 'In Progress' then 2
        when item_name = 'Passed' then 3
        when item_name = 'Exempt' then 4
    else 5
    end, item_name;
```

Expected results that I need

```
New
In Progress 
Passed
Expired
Exempt
```

Actual results that I am getting:

```
New 
In Progress
Passed
Exempt
```

Is there a way to hardcode `Expired` along with the other items to be displayed when I run the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table ddl used and insert statement.

```
  CREATE TABLE ITEM_TABLE
   (    ITEM_NAME VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
   ) ;


Insert into ITEM_TABLE (ITEM_NAME) values ('NEW');
Insert into ITEM_TABLE (ITEM_NAME) values ('In Progress');
Insert into ITEM_TABLE (ITEM_NAME) values ('passed');
Insert into ITEM_TABLE (ITEM_NAME) values ('Exempt');
```

If I understand you correctly. This should do it.

```
 SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            item_name
        FROM
            item_table
        UNION
        SELECT
            'hard_coded_Value' item_name
        FROM
            item_table
    )
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN item_name = 'New'          THEN
            1
        WHEN item_name = 'In Progress'  THEN
            2
        WHEN item_name = 'Passed'       THEN
            3
        WHEN item_name = 'Exempt'       THEN
            4
        WHEN ITEM_NAME = 'hard_coded_Value' then
        5
        ELSE
            6
    END,
    item_name;
```

I can't really validate the query since you haven't provided some ddl to test with but this is the generally how I would tackle a problem like this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. The first query adds a new column with the value `Expired` but I need a new row to be added rather than a new column. Can you elaborate more about the second query? Because running it returns the following error `ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression`

Comment: I updated my answer. it should work for you now. I simply take 2 datasets and union them together  and finally I do the order by.  Let me know if there is something you don't understand